# Need help in base voltage of N Mosfet in CNC AIr Spray circuit

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, relay, solid-state-relay

I'm changing my CNC air spraying circuit.

I'm simulating this circuit in Falstad, but I'm not getting what I want... Didn't actually assembled it in real life yet this way.

What I need is:

When the switch is on the PWM controlled position, the Air flows through the solenoid and it's rate of pulses is controlled by an SSR that is controlled by the MCU. The 5V signal that feed the gate of the Mosfet should be at 0V, or at least the Mosfet shouldn't be on.

When the switch is on the OFF position, the Air flow should stop, and the Mosfet also shouldn't be on.

When the switch is on the Always On position, the Air flows through the solenoid and the the 5V signal that feed the gate of the Mosfet should be at 5V, so another Input on the MCU gets HIGH and the MCU tells the SSR to be always ON.

In my falstad sim, I'm getting the 5V signal on the gate of the Mosfet  on the 3 scenarios, and I need 5V at the gate of the N Mosfet only at the Always On position. Why it does is get 5V in the Off and in the PWM positions, even if the 5V line is not grounded in these two positions?

How can I correct it?

Thanks!

[image: Circuit]

Falstad simulation Link:

[Circuit Simulation Link in Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEDoE4DMAWATKhl0A2AdnVW0gA4RNJkb1kBTAWjDACgA3ENwkdJUy8w-dtiiTaIbMLrzoCDmGLVMlOmEzD1dbAn5io0CWGhhUl4itSUwlEpQTFjkJGHjxXEiq7BIYRHAOAHcZaXEadXAwCUhQqOpI7STtKA4AZQYJFOyBQmo9EAAzAEMAGwBnJhkBBNz9flz0InSwvgEhESbo%20LCLCXQEU3IBSDkEjoRYkA1kGb7wUdyBzomwlv5pnPQJbbbumNNsJIX60XBCTVHReQTV26XB8YOO3Kmz-tH91dzFzF28x2OV692%20MxO1H2i0hQIErWhHAA5od9lMrpJ-tEiGpsa1-hdHpgLo0DsT%20KSGgZ0gAnATDGSUNQkpmSDzwBK7Og4xnUHnxAAeNGwgwQjG0ECGTXASAA8sVihwhS1JbYaJAcpAIMJ-CAAILlEKlACelQAOpVZQA7JU0Zzq4QGFy0Z0ykAABQA6gBZC0AYwA9laAC40gPlcpMAAmFo4xXC3IKT3yfNMinV9xORwT2cWcx%204LinIZPKGPlZ8R45JTNBZhSkdACmMUCVhPNkicKnN8pZLSZhrPbrOwxCLQuwGOw6El05kWBobu9AGEAKoWgCSVoADgBXYO2vRZidz7Vu2QANVt%20BcFEYBiQFGluoy4aYVoDAEso7b0MRhC1GDIQZWh1JAEEvIV2H4X9GBUaDiCfJAADkLW9ANKmKJh9wAI3ABDZj0YgXC0RhBRlYQk2nCRrAXZ8MgAJX9INQ3DSMY0qbDjVQ1dbUwQgmhHZBiQYOhQJAXcqmjC1inKAMQh-exhVEqhhXFN0lyDSpg1KENpNk%20ShT4sRZ2cTR5zEjSAFstxpJhKkqAMaQtPUPxpXj7RHNRiAfOxaKQFy3MMhlcDUShAK1PyQAAMX03jUEIlx8FQRlRLdJCAzivRLGQbBJQ1SKYrk21ZAffABABGQxQKxznMNE1zUtG0gA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems with your circuit.

1. You need to pull the MOSFET's gate down with a resistor in order for it to go down to 0V when the switch is off - the gate acts like a capacitor so if you charge it up you need to have a way to discharge it too
2. Your "PWM controlled" position and the "Always On" position will have the same effect - a PWM'ed solenoid. In both cases the positive supply to the solenoid is controlled by the PWM'ed SSR, so the solenoid will never see a constant DC supply
3. You're showing that you want to switch the negative end of the 5V supply for the "Always On" switch position - but unless you have a 'free-floating' battery or a supply which is completely isolated from all the other supplies in our system that's not going to work

Assuming you're able to rearrange your circuit a bit - particularly the position of the SSR, I'd suggest the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKFpdU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switch here is only a 2-position because that's all that I was offered - in reality you'd use a 3-position switch so that you could have an Off position too.
So with the switch in the right position, the SSR PWMs the solenoid.
With the switch in the left position, the SSR is switched out of the circuit and the solenoid is always on.
With the switch in either the right position or (invisible) middle Off position, the  'MCU In Always On' input will turn the solenoid On.